# How to rewrite on htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to substitute the character `%26` for `&` and `%3D` for `=` in my URL:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/?sort-by=title%26listing_types%3Dcars
```

I tried the rewrite below but it does not work

```
RewriteRule ^dir/?$ ?sort-by=$1&listing-types=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It can be just decoded into `title&listing_types=cars`

Comment: urldecode does not work

Comment: `echo urldecode('title&listing_types=cars')` gives me: 
`title&listing_types=cars`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^dir/?$ ?sort-by=$1&listing-types=$2 [QSA,L]
> ```

Your backreferences `$1` and `$2` don't actually refer to anything so these will always be *empty* (resulting in empty URL parameters). However, `$n` backreferences refer back to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which does not match against the query string anyway. You would need `%n` type backreferences that refer back to the last matched *CondPattern* in a preceding `RewriteCond` directive.

This also looks like it should ideally be a *redirect*, rather than an *internal rewrite*? Otherwise, you run the risk of *duplicate content*.

> ```
> http://www.example.com/dir/?sort-by=title%26listing_types%3Dcars
> ```

You can do something like the following to match the above URL and replace the appropriate characters:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(sort-by=.*)%26(listing_types)%3D(.*)
RewriteRule ^(dir/)$ /$1?%1&%2=%3 [R,L]
```

The above would temporarily (302) redirect `/dir/?sort-by=<anything1>%26listing_types%3D<anything2>` to `/dir/?sort-by=<anything1>&listing_types=<anything2>`. Change `R` to `R=301` if this should be permanent, but only once you have confirmed it is working OK.

`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. "dir/") and `%1`, `%2` and `%3` are backreferences to the corresponding captured groups in the preceding *CondPattern* in order to reconstruct the query string.

If you specifically need this to be an *internal rewrite* then remove the `R` flag (and optionally remove the slash prefix on the *substitution*).

---

> ```
> http://www.example.com/dir/?sort-by=title%26listing_types%3Dcars
> ```

As mentioned in comments, you could instead handle this entirely in your server-side code. For example, in PHP you could do something like:

```
<?php
$queryString = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
parse_str($queryString,$urlParams);
print_r($urlParams);
?>
```

Given the above request URL, this will output:

```
Array
(
    [sort-by] => title
    [listing_types] => cars
)
```